# How can I unregister Git VCS root?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I would like to use a Java project from GitHub. I'd like to write and compile it using Idea Community Edition 14.0, on my machine, and to perform Pull/Push etc to Git. To synchronize the project with Git, I have performed the following steps:

- Idea - VCS → Checkout from version control - GitHub (master branch was downloaded)
- Idea - *project_name* → Git → Repository → Branches → *my_branch_name* → Checkout as new local branch

After these actions it was possible to work with Java classes in *my_branch_name* project. But after some time the following message appeared:

> The directory *my_branch_name* is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings

I have clicked "Add root". And now I cannot add new Java classes, do not see one public class from the another, can not run main procedure - there is message "Process finished with exit code 1" (but it was run successfully before).

I understand that I have added some new root? How can I fix it now?